# update mysql table so that the sort order will be random and stored to column

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a table that I want to randomly sort but not with rand() as the results will be paginated so I would not be able to have the continuation of the sort order on page 2.

I made a column named sort that I would like to re-generate every 5 minutes using scheduled update.

Now how do I do the update query?

This does not work :-(

```
UPDATE mytable SET sort=(select ID from mytable order by rand())
```

Is there any way to do it? To make values in sort column from 1 to number of rows in random order?

UPDATE: I have this slightly wrong. I am changing the sort every 5 minutes. If some visitor will be there on page 1 at one time and after 5 minutes the sort will be different and page 2 will have wrong results. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

why not

```
UPDATE mytable SET sort=rand()
```

Comment: My column is integer, so I get only 0 and 1 in it. I can make some other column type I guess, but I can get duplicate values if I use rand().

Comment: why does it matter if you get duplicates?  The distribution of records will still be random

Comment: You are correct. Thank you. Sometimes you can not see the simple answer due to thinking complex one. What kind of column type to use for it? double or float? Which would be faster on order by sort?

Comment: it depends on how many records you have.  you can also convert to an int by moving the exponent.  Just make sure your multiplication coefficient is large enough for the size of the table.

Comment: Yes, thanx, rand()*1000... is sorting int faster than float column types?

Comment: it depends.  it shouldn't matter much.  I wouldn't worry about this until your query runs slowly.  then profile and optimize.